# caption misplacement with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, koma-script

I'm having trouble with the placement of subcaptions with `\subfloat` when using tikzpicture.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
               11pt,
               ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}
\setcapindent{0em}
\setcapwidth{0.9\textwidth}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={footnotesize},labelfont={bf,footnotesize}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    momentum/.style={postaction={decorate},
decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.8]{>}}}},
}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\subfloat[Winkel zwischen 1 und 3 am kleinsten]{
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=0.3]
    \centering
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(5,1);
      \node[anchor=north]at(5,1){2};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(4,9);
      \node[anchor=east]at(4,9){1};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(6,9);
      \node[anchor=west]at(6,9){3};
  \end{tikzpicture}
} \hspace{1cm}
\subfloat[Winkel zwischen 2 und 3 am kleinsten]{
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=0.3]
    \centering
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(5,1);
      \node[anchor=north]at(5,1){1};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(4,9);
      \node[anchor=east]at(4,9){2};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(6,9);
      \node[anchor=west]at(6,9){3};
  \end{tikzpicture}
} \hspace{1cm}
\subfloat[Alle Winkel etwa gleich groß]{
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=0.3]
    \centering
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(5,1);
      \node[anchor=north]at(5,1){1};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(1,8);
      \node[anchor=east]at(1,8){2};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(9,8);
      \node[anchor=west]at(9,8){3};
  \end{tikzpicture} }
\caption{Bildunterschrift}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It compiles, but the subcaptions I set via `\subfloat[...]` are badly misplaced:

[image: output of the mwe]

I'm completely lost at this point, since using the exact same code in the beamer-class works perfectly fine.

I want to avoid using the packages `subfigure` or `subcaption`.
I somewhere read that it might be a good idea to wrap the subfloats in minipages but it didn't work.

Any ideas on this?

**edit**
I found a solution that works for me using the hints of @Troy and @John_Kormylo
I commented out the `\setcapwidth{0.9\textwidth}` and added it to every figure and table except the ones where i use tikzpicture...
Putting `\setcapwidth{\textwidth}` inside the problematic subfloats didn't change anything.

Comment: If you replace scrreprt with report, the problem goes away.  KOMA handles its own captions and basically ignores other caption packages..

Comment: I find that if you comment away `\setcapwidth{0.9\textwidth}`, the problem goes away as well

Comment: @Troy - You can also move \setcapwidth... inside the subfig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KOMA classes are not really compatible with `subfig`. You can use `subcaption` instead.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  ngerman
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}
\setcapindent{0em}
\setcapwidth{0.9\textwidth}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={footnotesize},labelfont={bf,footnotesize}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
  momentum/.style={
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.8]{>}},
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb]

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=0.3]
  \draw[momentum](5,5)--(5,1);
  \node[anchor=north]at(5,1){2};
  \draw[momentum](5,5)--(4,9);
  \node[anchor=east]at(4,9){1};
  \draw[momentum](5,5)--(6,9);
  \node[anchor=west]at(6,9){3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Winkel zwischen 1 und 3 am kleinsten}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=0.3]
  \draw[momentum](5,5)--(5,1);
  \node[anchor=north]at(5,1){1};
  \draw[momentum](5,5)--(4,9);
  \node[anchor=east]at(4,9){2};
  \draw[momentum](5,5)--(6,9);
  \node[anchor=west]at(6,9){3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Winkel zwischen 2 und 3 am kleinsten}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=0.3]
  \draw[momentum](5,5)--(5,1);
  \node[anchor=north]at(5,1){1};
  \draw[momentum](5,5)--(1,8);
  \node[anchor=east]at(1,8){2};
  \draw[momentum](5,5)--(9,8);
  \node[anchor=west]at(9,8){3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Alle Winkel etwa gleich groß}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Bildunterschrift}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i originally didn't want to do this because I'm using `\subfloat` in my whole document but i guess I'll change my mind since this simply looks way better than what  I have now.

Answer (score 4):

Since KOMA-Script version 3.20 you can use `\setcapdynwidth` instead `\setcapwidth`. From the KOMA-Script documentation:

> Please note, `\setcapwidth` sets the `width` immediately to the value of parameter width like `\setlength` would do. If you instead want the value of `width` when the caption is set, you can use `\setcapdynwidth`. There can be differences in the result, if you, e. g., use lengths like `\linewidth` or other commands as argument `width`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
               11pt,
               ngerman]{scrreprt}[2016/05/10]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}
\setcapindent{0em}
\setcapdynwidth{0.9\textwidth}% <- changed, needs KOMA-Script version 3.20
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={footnotesize},labelfont={bf,footnotesize}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    momentum/.style={postaction={decorate},
decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.8]{>}}}},
}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\subfloat[Winkel zwischen 1 und 3 am kleinsten]{
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=0.3]
    \centering
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(5,1);
      \node[anchor=north]at(5,1){2};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(4,9);
      \node[anchor=east]at(4,9){1};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(6,9);
      \node[anchor=west]at(6,9){3};
  \end{tikzpicture}
} \hspace{1cm}
\subfloat[Winkel zwischen 2 und 3 am kleinsten]{
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=0.3]
    \centering
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(5,1);
      \node[anchor=north]at(5,1){1};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(4,9);
      \node[anchor=east]at(4,9){2};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(6,9);
      \node[anchor=west]at(6,9){3};
  \end{tikzpicture}
} \hspace{1cm}
\subfloat[Alle Winkel etwa gleich groß]{
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=0.3]
    \centering
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(5,1);
      \node[anchor=north]at(5,1){1};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(1,8);
      \node[anchor=east]at(1,8){2};
      \draw[momentum](5,5)--(9,8);
      \node[anchor=west]at(9,8){3};
  \end{tikzpicture} }
\caption{Bildunterschrift}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: running `pdflatex --version` tells me that I'm using pdfTeX 3.1415... so slightly too old for your solution :P Thank you anyways, I'll keep it in mind

Comment: 3.20 is the number of the KOMA-Script version (and not pdfTeX).